# Canvas text rendering

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, drawimage, drawtext

I can really use some help, my goal is to add few lines to the canvas in different places, it means to use the function `drawText` few times, for some reason if I don't use `drawText` inside the `onload` of `drawImage` the text does not rendering I am really stuck and can use some help, my main target it to make website that can edit pictures and make memes (e.g.: https://imgflip.com/memegenerator)and adding text line is what i am getting stuck on because I don't understand how to render new text line while save the old one, every time i start new line its like the image rendering all over again and start from the beginning.

```
// Function to load image on the canvas
function drawImg(url) {
    gCurrLineIdx = getCurrLineIdx();
    let currLine = gMeme.lines[gCurrLineIdx];
    const img = new Image();

    img.src = url;
    img.onload = () => {
        gCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, gElCanvas.width, gElCanvas.height);
        //If you dont call drawText the text does not render to the canvas
        drawText(currLine.txt, currLine.size, currLine.fontColor, currLine.strokeColor, currLine.align, currLine.font, gElCanvas.width / 2, currLine.y);
    };
}

// Function to add text on the canvas
function drawText(text = '', fontSize = 20, fontColor = 'white', strokeColor = 'black', align = 'center', font = "ariel", x = gElCanvas.width / 2, y = 20) {
    gCtx.strokeStyle = strokeColor;
    gCtx.fillStyle = fontColor;
    gCtx.font = `${fontSize}px ${font}`;
    gCtx.textAlign = align;
    gCtx.fillText(text, x, y);
    gCtx.strokeText(text, x, y);
}

//Function to add new text line on the canvas.
function onAddTextLine() {
    let textInput = document.getElementById('text-input');
    textInput.value = '';

    addTextLine();
    gCurrLineIdx = getCurrLineIdx();
    var currLine = gMeme.lines[gCurrLineIdx];
    drawText(currLine.txt, currLine.size, currLine.fontColor, currLine.strokeColor, currLine.align, currLine.font, gElCanvas.width / 2, currLine.y);
}
```

Comment: My guess would be that the text *is* rendered, but then, when the image is loaded, it's rendered *on top* of the text.

Comment: @Yoshi 
I thought about it the problem is when i try to add a new text line it just delete the old line I wrote and does not write the new link only the image in the background

Comment: The problem might be that you expect *too much* of the canvas element. Ultimately it's just a bunch of pixels. You're responsible to keep/create your own data model.

Comment: @Yoshi
so what does it means that draw text must be called inside drawImage and to add new text line i need save my canvas in data and re render it to the canvas?

Comment: In general I'd say yes. You want to have a representation of your model that exist without the canvas. And on every change to that model (e.g. new background image, new text, text changes, ...), you re-paint it to a fresh canvas. Though, this render process needs to handle async operations (like with the backround image). For this you could use simple promises (e.g. async/await). To speed things up, you could use multiple canvas that get merged at a last step.

Answer (score 0):

The question I see here is:

> how to render new text line while save the old one

Looks like in your code you are drawing things independently, below is a different approach the `class Meme` has a few functions to add text and image but every time anything change the entire canvas is cleared (`clearRect`) and every element is re-drawn, the magic is in the `this.draw()`, that is the call to the common function that does all the drawing.

To keep my sample small I hard-coded many of the things you had as parameters, it should be easy for you to reintroduce them if you need

```js
class Meme {
  constructor(ctx, width, height) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.ctx.font = '80px Arial';
    this.ctx.fillStyle = "blue"
    this.ctx.textAlign = "center"
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
  }

  addHeadText(text) {
    this.htext = text;
    this.draw();
  }

  addFootText(text) {
    this.ftext = text;
    this.draw();
  }

  addImage(image_src) {
    this.image = new Image();
    this.image.src = image_src;
    this.image.onload = () => {
      this.draw()
    };
  }

  draw() {
    this.ctx.beginPath();
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height)
    if (this.image) {
      this.ctx.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    }
    if (this.htext) {
      this.ctx.textBaseline = "top";
      this.ctx.fillText(this.htext, this.width / 2, 0);
    }
    if (this.ftext) {
      this.ctx.textBaseline = "bottom";
      this.ctx.fillText(this.ftext, this.width / 2, this.height);
    }
    this.ctx.closePath();
  }
}

const canvas = document.getElementById('c');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

meme = new Meme(ctx, canvas.width, canvas.height)
meme.addHeadText("Hello");
meme.addFootText("World");
meme.addImage("https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png");

document.getElementById('htext').onkeyup = (event) => {
  meme.addHeadText(event.srcElement.value);
};
document.getElementById('ftext').onkeyup = (event) => {
  meme.addFootText(event.srcElement.value);
};
```

```html
Head Text:<input type="text" id="htext" name="ftext" style="width: 140px;" value="Hello"><br>
Foot Text:<input type="text" id="ftext" name="ftext" style="width: 140px;" value="World"><br>

<canvas id="c" width=280 height=380 style="border:2px solid red;"></canvas>
```